# Does firebase support A/B testing for web application?

Tags: firebase, ab-testing

I try to create a Remote Config experiment for A/B testing on web application.

But when I click on *select an application*. It just show android and ios app, don't show web app.

[image]

So I want to ask that does firebase support A/B testing for web applications?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might be able to cobble it together. See https://amp.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/eqly8w/suggestions_for_ab_testing_on_web/

They’ve definitely added support for remote config on the web a few years back.

Depending on your use case - if you’re trying to do something simple (measure conversion on a button or a CTA) and are also using tools like Optimizely and Amplitude - they let you do this too.

Alternatively (disclaimer - I work for them :) tools like statsig.com are purpose built to enable this - and if your volumes are low - their free tier can be sufficient.